# How can I use tooltips while text-ellipsis is applied to an element?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an account number which is more than 100 characters and I need to limit these with overflow hidden and I have to show the full account no using a tooltip.

Here is my code

```
<span class="text-ellipsis"
    Tooltipcomponent
     Tooltipcomponent-with-text-ellipses=yes
     Tooltipcomponent-settext = "{account no}">
     <Strong float:right col-md-4 text-ellipsis ----------------*
        ng-bind = {account no}>
     </Strong>
</Span>
```

From the above code I am not seeing tooltip and I am able to do overflow-hidden to account number.

*----- if I remove text-ellipsis in the strong tag I can see my tooltip but not able to achieve overflow hidden

Please guide me.

Comment: What have you tried yourself and can you share the code with us?

Comment: Post the css with the correct html code

Comment: Here is my HTML code.                                                                            <div class="pull-left col-xs-8 text-ellipsis">.                                            <Span ib-tooltip                                                                                          ib-tooltip-placement ="left" ib-tooltip-trigger='mouseEnter'.         Ib-show-on-ellipsis="true"    ib-tooltip-text="{{account number}}".        <Strong ng-bind="account number"></strong>.                              </Span></div>

Answer (score 0):

Try  " Title "  attribute.
 title = "Your message here that to be shown in tooltip";